# Capturar varios parametros via .htaccess y php

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest

Tengo este **.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ miphp.php?peticion=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ miphp.php [QSA,NC,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ miphp.php [QSA,NC,L] 
</IfModule>
```

Si pongo **localhost/carpeta/parametroUno** funciona perfectamente y el php recibe el parámetro petición como *parametroUno*....

Me gustaría poder capturar más de un *parámetro*, como mínimo 3...

¿Cómo podría hacer esto en el **.htaccess** para que pueda recibir hasta 3 *parámetros*?

Comment: Sergio para ponerle mas de un parametro a una php seria asi `miphp.php?peticion1=$1&peticion2=$2&peticion=$3...` sucesibamente

Answer (score 0):

El comentario de @JordiTurell en tu pregunta apunta bien, pero hay que aclarar lo siguiente:

- En la **primera parte de la rule** (antes del espacio) cada parámetro está encerrado entre paréntesis `()`
- En esta **primera parte** puede haber tantos parámetros como se desee. A modo de ejemplo (que conste que esta rule es incorrecta, le faltaria la *segunda parte*):

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$
  ```

  ***Eso serían 3 posibles parámetros.***
- En la **segunda parte de la rule** cada parámetro *se interpreta por orden de aparición*, con el simbolo `$` seguido del número correspondiente a su orden. Por ejemplo, en el ejemplo anterior, podríamos usar **$1** para el *primer paréntesis*, **$2** para el *segundo paréntesis*, y **$3** para el *tercer paréntesis*, y si hubiera más pues seguiriamos la misma lógica.
- En la **segunda parte de la rule** no hace falta usar todos los parámetros que son definidos en la primera parte. Su puede usar *ninguno*, *varios* o *todos*, por los motivos que sean (no voy a entrar en los motivos, cada web es un mundo).

  Por ejemplo, estas rules serian todas válidas de forma independiente *(no juntas porque unas precederian a las otras y no llegarian a ejecutarse)* a pesar que no siempre se usen todos sus parámetros:

  ```
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ miphp.php
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ miphp.php?param=$1
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ miphp.php?param=$1&param2=$2
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ miphp.php?param=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3
  ```

  ***Nota***: No pongo las opciones al final `[]` porque no forman parte de la pregunta, y son dependientes de lo que se quiera hacer en cada caso.

Evidentemente los parámetros de la **primera parte** no son siempre con esta sintaxis `(.*)`.

Hay múltitud de posibles variaciones pues se basan en las *expresiones regulares* denominadas **PCRE** (*Perl Compatible Regular Expression*).

En este enlace encontrarás una lista de ellas aplicadas a **mod_rewrite**:  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html